# Using fold expression to initialize static constexpr class data member doesn't compile

Tags: c++, c++17, variadic-templates, fold-expression

I am confused about a particular piece of code that won't compile even though very similar pieces of code do compile.

This will not compile:

```
#include <bitset>
template<std::size_t ...GROUPS>
class Foo
{
    static constexpr std::size_t BIT_COUNT = (GROUPS + ...);
    using Bits = std::bitset<BIT_COUNT>;
    Bits bits;
};

class Bar : public Foo<6, 6, 6, 6>{};
```

With the enlightening error `1>c:\...\source.cpp(5): error C2059: syntax error: '...'`.

This compiles:

```
#include <bitset>
template<std::size_t ...GROUPS>
class Foo
{
    using Bits = std::bitset<(GROUPS + ...)>;
    Bits bits;
};

class Bar : public Foo<6, 6, 6, 6>{};
```

This also compiles:

```
#include <bitset>
template<auto... t>
constexpr auto static_sum()
{
    return (t + ...);
}

template<std::size_t ...GROUPS>
class Foo
{
    static constexpr std::size_t BIT_COUNT = static_sum<GROUPS...>();
    using Bits = std::bitset<BIT_COUNT>;
    Bits bits;
};

class Bar : public Foo<6, 6, 6, 6>{};
```

I'm compiling with MSVC++ in Visual studio 15.9.8.
What am I missing?

**Edit:** I'm compiling with the `/std:c++17` flag. Trying `/std:latest` did not help.

Comment: Compiler error, please report.

Comment: Compile fine here with gcc/clang  [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dcc611fedec8b576)

Comment: So probably a msvc bug.

Comment: Support for C++17 fold expressions in Visual Studio was put off for a long time (partly because it was buggy on first release, like this). Rest assured it works correctly iff it compiles, so there's no chance for false positives. Try setting your C++ standard for the project to C++17 or Latest, or the like and see if those newer standards fix it.

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot to mention. I'm compiling with the `/std:c++17` already. I've also tried `/std:latest` to no avail. Updated my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reported as a possible compiler bug: [Bug report](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/487333/using-fold-expression-to-initialize-static-constex.html)

**Edit:** This is a confirmed bug and a fix has been released in Visual Studio 2019.

I've also slightly simplified my final solution to the following:

```
static constexpr std::size_t BIT_COUNT = [](int i) { return i; }((GROUPS + ...));
```